# ASP.NET GridView BoundField which contains DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, databound

I have a GridView which displays some data from list of objects using BoundField columns.

```
<asp:GridView ID="UserGridView" runat="server"
            ItemType="User" DataKeyNames="Login" SelectMethod="GetUsers"
            UpdateMethod="UserGridView_UpdateItem"
 AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowEditButton="True" CancelImageUrl="~/Content/cancel.png" DeleteImageUrl="~/Content/trash.png" EditImageUrl="~/Content/edit.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/Content/edit.png" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="User Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Login" HeaderText="Login" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Profile" HeaderText="Profile" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

In my case, field **Profile** can take on of 3 predefined values - "*admin*", "*customer*", "*salesperson*".
So I want I would be able to select on of this values from DropDownList when GridView is in Edit mode. Can anyone help me?

Comment: One more thing - I want to get possible values for dropdownlist from enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace: `<asp:BoundField DataField="Profile" HeaderText="Profile" />`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Profile">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Profile" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Profile") %>' Visible = "false" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProfile" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```